# what is the TextMargin size added default in DrawString method

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

While drawing string using MeasureString, it draws the given text in given position with some padding.

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
   base.OnPaint(e);

   Size size = Size.Ceiling(e.Graphics.MeasureString("like", this.Font));

   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(15, 15, size.Width, size.Height);

   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, rect);
   e.Graphics.DrawString("like", this.Font, Brushes.Violet, rect);
}
```

[image]

I want to know, what is the padding difference added to the given point for drawing measurestring.

Please anyone clarify on this.

Comment: While drawing string using measure string? Are you measuring or drawing

Comment: @EpicKip - Please refer to the sample code

Comment: `While drawing string using MeasureString` < not possible. But i think the padding ik 1/8em or something

Comment: The padding is meant to allow you to add several parts in e.g. different colors without touching. So it depends on the font. You can get an (almost) unpadded measure when adding the paramter [typographic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.stringformat.generictypographic(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I can't comment yet -- I assume your question about padding is "why there is still a little bit of blue colour on the left of the word 'like'" -- I'm guessing that's related with the font OR possibly because of the Ceiling of the 'size'?